# resolving out of memory error in MAT LAB

Tags: image, matlab, compression, fractals

In my code written for fractal image compression I got an error as :

```
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in tformarray (line 228)
    B(prod(fsize_B)) = A(1);

Error in imtransform (line 275)
B = tformarray(args.A, args.tform, args.resampler, tdims_a, tdims_b, ...

Error in test1_UI (line 85)
        I = imtransform(I,tform);
```

How can i resolve this?

my code where this happens is as follows :

```
[optimizer, metric] = imregconfig('monomodal');
% find the affine transformation from the damain block to range block

    for rR=1:nrR
        for cR=1:ncR
            i=1;
            for rd=1:nrD
                for cd=1:ncD
                    s(i)= ssim(caR{rR,cR},imresize(caD{rd,cd},[64 64]));
                    if s(i)== d(rR,cR)
                        tformO = imregtform(caD{rd,cd},caR{rR,cR},'affine',optimizer,metric);
                        T(rR,cR) = tformO;
                    else
                        i=i+1;
                    end
                end
            end
            d(rR,cR) = max(s);
        end
    end

    clear d

    % A - any initial image
    A = imread('lena_jpgx80.jpg');
    I = A;

    for rR=1:nrR
        for cR=1:ncR
            tform = maketform('affine',T(rR,cR).T);
            I = imtransform(I,tform);
            i=i+1;
        end
    end

    imshow(I)
```

Comment: You'r variables are probably double precision, according to what you want you can change some of them to single precision it's likely that you won't get out of memory then.

Comment: using I = single(A) does not work!

Comment: what about `I=uint8(A);` ?

Comment: You should use `A = single(A)` or `I = single(A);clear(A);`

Comment: A = single(A) or I = single(A);clear(A); doesn't work either!

Comment: Please provide a short self-contained example that produces an out of memory error on your machine, but which we can run ourselves to figure out what might be the problem. This should include the image being processed. Provide this by editing your question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to prepare an example, and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format a post.

Comment: up to this point program run well after this point this error happens T is a set of affine transformations                    % A - any initial image
    A = imread('lena_jpgx80.jpg');
    I = A;

    for rR=1:nrR
        for cR=1:ncR
            tform = maketform('affine',T(rR,cR).T);
            I = imtransform(I,tform);
            i=i+1;
        end
    end